# non-linear trend reduction using thresholds

Tags: image-processing, fitting, signal-processing

Doing some mappings of the earth magnetic field results in the left-hand figure below (which consists of 181 profiles):

[image: Non-linear trend reduction without threshold]

To improve this I tried a non-linear trend reduction using, for example,

```
lm = LinearModelFit[data, {a, a^2,a^3,a^4,a^5,a^6,a^7,a^8,a^9},a];
```

(middle figure) and

```
lm = LinearModelFit[data, {a, a^2,a^3}, a];
```

(right-hand figure), respectively. Data was defined as `data = Import[#1, "Table"];` within a `Scan` environment.

Because of the occurrence of artifacts I feel that I have to consider something like thresholds, so that the reduction will be only considered within a threshold (for example -20 <= t <= 20) and the data outside of this range should not be affected by these calculations.

I have no idea how to handle this effectively. My idea first was to use a lot of `IF`'s and to separate each profile into several parts. But this will be ineffective and time-consuming...

I would like to handle all those 181 profiles separately before combining them.

---

@R.M.: This is the code I used so far:

```
SetDirectory[SystemDialogInput["Directory"]]
listOfFileNames = ReadList["listing.txt", Word];

Scan[
 (data = Import[#1, "Table"];
   newfile = StringReplace[#1, ".dat" -> "-red.dat"];
   wfile = OpenWrite[newfile, FormatType -> StandardForm];
   Clear[lm]; Clear[a]; Clear[neu]; Clear[aha]; 
   start = First[First[data]]; mdim = Length[data];
   lm = LinearModelFit[
     data, {a, a^2, a^3, a^4, a^5, a^6, a^7, a^8, a^9}, a];
   Do[aha = Last[Take[data, {m, m}]]; ywert = Last[aha]; 
    xwert = First[aha]; neu[m] = ywert - lm[xwert], {m, mdim}];
   Do[WriteString[newfile, start + (m - 1)*0.05  , "  "]; 
    Write[newfile,    neu[m]], {m, mdim}];
   Close[wfile];
   Clear;
   ) &,
 listOfFileNames
 ]
```

With listing.txt:

09500.dat
09525.dat
09550.dat
09575.dat
09600.dat
09625.dat
09650.dat
09675.dat
etc

---

@belisarius:

[image: example 2]

This shows the quality of data outside of the pipeline I want to achieve

@Mr.Wizard: With VSNR there is no effect on the data:
[image]

Comment: "*To improve this*" -- what does that mean in this context?

Comment: It is hard to think about this because it is muddled with a lot of domain specific details. Could you strip all of it to a basic minimal toy example (working)?

Comment: there are small stripes (parallel to the direction of measurement, i.e. from bottom to the top) in the figure, which should be removed. The "background" (all the area outside of the strong anomaly) should be smoothed by this way, so when enhancing the contrast of the picture no small artefacts are disturbing the background. I have to enhance the contrast to be able to detect weak archaeological features, if there are any...

Comment: Does this appear helpful? http://www.math.univ-toulouse.fr/~weiss/Codes/VSNR/VNSR_VariationalStationaryNoiseRemover.html

Comment: Could you post an example of your expected result?

Comment: Did you think of using image processing to improve your data?

Comment: What is the variable _t_ you mentioned for thresholding ?

Comment: Mr.Wizard: Thanks a lot, but these routines don't solve my problem Vitaliy Kaurov: yes, but I found that none of the image processing routines were useful belisarius: yes, t should define the threshold

Comment: Harald, it *looks* like it should apply to your problem, but I didn't try.  Will you explain how it fails?

Comment: Mr. Wizard: Sorry for the delay of my answer. Meanwhile I had the opportunity to test VSNR with MATLAB. To show you the result, I will put the screenshot at the end of my answer. There seems to be no influence on the data at all.

Answer (score 2):

It's a shame there is no raw data to work with, since this is an interesting problem but quantization, resampling and jpeg compression have probably wiped out any subtle features that may have been present.

I think the basic idea outlined in the question is workable. The proposal is to high-pass filter each column of the image by fitting a polynomial with some small number of terms and subtracting the fit from the original data. The strong anomaly should be excluded from the fit. There is also a triangular region with no data in the top-right corner of the image, this should be excluded too.

We can also see that there is a clear separation between the top and bottom half of the image, so it makes sense to process both halves separately.

Starting from the image in the question, manually cropped to include only the left hand image:

Load the image, convert to grayscale and extract just the top half:

```
picture = ColorConvert[Import["cropped.jpg"], "Grayscale"];
image = ImageTake[picture, {2, 236}]
```

[image]

Using `Binarize` we can identify the regions with either no data (pixel values equal to 127/255) or where the anomaly is (pixel values close to 0 or 1)

```
nodata = ColorNegate[Binarize[image, {127/255, 127/255}]] ~ Dilation ~ 1;
anomaly = Binarize[image, {0.05, 0.95}];
{nodata, anomaly}
```

[image]

Combine the two regions using `ImageMultiply` (plus an `Erosion` to fill in the gaps a bit). I've also created an image showing the outline of the excluded regions.

```
mask = ImageMultiply[nodata, anomaly] ~ Erosion ~ 2;
edge = ImageApply[{#1, 0, 0} &, GradientFilter[mask, 1]];
{mask, edge}
```

[image]

Next convert the images to arrays and do the fits. I've used terms up to $x^{20}$. For each column, `Pick` is used to select the data which is not in the excluded region.

```
mask = ImageData @ mask;
image = ImageData @ image;

xvals = Range[0., 1, 1/(Length[mask] - 1)];

fit = Transpose @ Table[Fit[
      Pick[Transpose[{xvals, image[[All, j]]}], mask[[All, j]], 1],
      x^Range[0, 20], x] /. x -> xvals
    , {j, Length @ First @ image}];
```

The fitted data looks like this:

```
Image[fit]
```

[image]

Subtracting the fitted data from the original image and enhancing the contrast:

```
Image[0.5 + 3 (image - fit) mask] ~ ImageAdd ~ edge
```

[image]

If you repeat the process with the bottom half of the image and stack them together, you get this:

[image]

The strength of the filtering can be altered by using more or less terms in the fit.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. If you are interested, you can get the raw data via: https://www.dropbox.com/s/r7wnjb1nhx9drbz/ois.xyz - Harald. P.S.: z = 99999 are dummy values